# Exploratory Factor Analysis vs. PCA

Tags: machine-learning, pca, factor-analysis

There is a very nice and clear way to illustrate the geometry of PCA. Is there a similar, geometrical way to illustrate Exploratory Factor Analysis? For example, we have 3D data and we’re using 2 factors. How can one visualise what happens when we do EFA?